# How do I access dynamic text on the stage from inside a movieclip which is inside another moveclip in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Before asking, I've read other articles for similar issues and have not been able to get it working. I have a dynamic text on the stage with the instance name of txtX. Then in action script in frame 1 of the main timeline I add an existing movie clip, mc1, using code:

```
var mc = new MC();
addChild(mc);
```

I then add another movieclip, mc2, with action script on frame 1 of the main timeline I add it as a child to mc1.

```
var mc2 = new MC2();
mc.addChild(mc2);
```

Now, in the class (created class for export AS) for mc2 I am trying to modify the text of the dynamic text but cannot for the life of me figure out how to reference it. I want to say:

```
stage.txtX.text = "blah blah";
```

or even

```
parent.parent.txtX.text = "blah blah";
```

but I usually get an error similar to:

```
Access of possibly undefined property txtX through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.
```

The error above is for the parent.parent.txtX.text line. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks. Also I know that the variable names are nonsensical but it's just for my example. In my code the names make much more sense.

Comment: This is the official explanation about display list and how to access things: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e26.html

Answer (score 0):

When you put a text field on your main timeline and give it an instance name of `txtX`,  it actually is not a direct child of stage.    The stage would be it's grandparent (the main/root timeline would be it's parent).

As such, if `mc1` & `mc2` are it's siblings (also on the main timeline),  you could access your text field like so:

```
MovieClip(parent).txtX.text = "Hello";
```

Alternatively, you can access the root (main) timeline with the `root` keyword:

```
MovieClip(root).txtX.text = "Hello";
```

And that should work on any timeline no matter how deep/nested.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out finally. Not sure if it was the correct way to do it but in the parent MoveieClip, I created a TextField in code:

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

public var txtX:TextField;
txtX = new TextField(); txtX.x=0; txtX.y=0; addChild(txtX);
public function changeTxt( t )
{
    tf = new TextFormat();
    tf.size=4;
    tf.color = 0xFFFF00;
    txtX.text = t;
    txtX.setTextFormat(tf);
}
```

Then in my MovieClip child class I called the parent's method like this:

```
MovieClip(parent).changeTxt( "Hello" );
```

A lot more work than I'd hoped for but it seems to work.